# How can set onClickListner fo buttons..?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to set OnclickListner for different buttons which are located in different xml layouts.

Comment: In different layouts? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use a definition like that directly in the XML-file:

```
<Button android:onClick="myClickHandler" />
```

After that you can create the method "myClickHandler" in your Code like that:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void myClickHandler(View target) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
  final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
             button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                 }
             });
```

Then all you need to do is reference the different buttons by their different ids set in the XML